# Spring Boot + Swagger + Swagger UI and @RequestBody has data type String

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I've got a problem using Spring Boot 1.4 and Swagger and Swagger UI. When using @RequestBody parameter is displaying as data type string. This does not seems correct.

```
@ApiOperation(value = "simple message resource")
@ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "message", value = "Message to send", required = true, dataType = "com.larmic.springboot.swagger.rest.dto.MessageDto", paramType = "body")
})
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/message", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = {"application/json", "application/xml"})
public void sendMessage(@RequestBody MessageDto message) {
    System.out.println("ping");
}
```

and

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "MessageDto")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@ApiModel(value = "MessageDto", description = "TODO")
public class MessageDto {

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Message content text", required = true, example = "some demo message")
    private String content;

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

I've found a lot of fixes using full name of MessageDto or setting correct value of @ApiModel but nothing seems to work.

I've created a full example here https://github.com/larmic/SpringBootAndSwaggerUI

Maybe someone can help.

Answer (score 12):

This appears to be a bug in Springfox ([#1344](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1344)). You could work around it by not using `@ApiImplicitParams`, but by annoting your method parameter itself with the `@ApiParam` annotation:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "simple message resource")
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/message", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = {"application/json", "application/xml"})
public void sendMessage(@ApiParam(name = "message", value = "Message to send", required = true) @RequestBody MessageDto message) {
    System.out.println("ping");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is working! I've pushed the fix to https://github.com/larmic/SpringBootAndSwaggerUI